# Atomic retrieving sequential range from SEQUENCE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a sequence and I want to atomically retrieve several sequential values from it.

As far as I know, sequences do not support transactions.

Standard `NEXT VALUE FOR` [syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370(v=sql.110).aspx) can not help, while in other databases it can be done like that.

I found `sp_sequence_get_range` [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878352.aspx), but I'm not sure if it is atomic. Testing such cases is quite tricky.

Is it possible?

Comment: "Atomic" as in "all or nothing"? What sort of partial would you expect?

Comment: I mean that I need sequential numbers without possible gaps caused by concurrent access to a sequence. For example, if two processes simultaneously request 10 numbers from sequence with value 0 I want them always to get ranges [0-9] and [10-19], without gaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes, sequences have the property you're looking for.

Now a little bit as to why. At their base, a sequence is just a row in a system table that has (among other things) a column that represents the current value in the sequence. Normally, when you call `NEXT VALUE FOR`, SQL Server fetches that current value, increments that value by 1, and finally returns the fetched value. When you use the `sp_sequence_get_range`, it does the same thing except it increments the value by the size of the range you asked for (e.g. if you called it with `@range_size = 10`, it increments the value by 10).

One thing that I was curious about was whether or not a rollback of a transaction that contained the `sp_sequence_get_range` procedure call also rolled back the allocation of that range. I'm happy to report that it does not. So, you needn't worry about two calls to that procedure getting the same value.

Lastly, I caution you against the fallacy of a gapless sequence. If you get a range and that thread dies for whatever reason (e.g. your application terminates, the SQL Server shuts down expectedly or unexpectedly), that sequence is lost forever. That is, there's no putting an "unused" range back in the queue so that the next call for a range gets that range.