# Does NEXT VALUE FOR @Sequence in SQL Server work in the same way as Interlocked.Increment() in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I wonder if SQL Server's `sequence` objects are atomic in increasing their internal counter as it happens with help of `Interlocked.Increment()` method. Who knows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a single SQL Server statement atomic and consistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468742/is-a-single-sql-server-statement-atomic-and-consistent) and [Atomic retrieving sequential range from SEQUENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407983/atomic-retrieving-sequential-range-from-sequence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if SQL Server's sequence objects are atomic in increasing their internal counter as it happens with help of Interlocked.Increment() method.

Yes.  SEQUENCE objects are guaranteed to never create the same NEXT VALUE multiple times, even if multiple sessions request the NEXT VALUE simultaneously.